# Iterating over 2 lists with REDUCE in Cypher/Neo4j

Tags: loops, foreach, neo4j, cypher, reduce

I have a list of similarities and a list of Ratings, and I would like to calculate a weighted average in a query on a graph in Neo4j

WITH REDUCE(x = 0, i IN similarities AND j in Ratings | x+i*j)*1.0 / REDUCE(y = 0, k IN similarities | y+k) AS WeightedRating

It says that j is not defined. Does anyone know how the syntax works? Should I use for each?

Answer (score 2):

You want to iterate the two lists in parallel?

Currently there is no direct way of doing it, but a workaround using an index

```
 WITH REDUCE(x = 0, idx in range(0,size(similarities)-1) 
             | x + similarities[idx]*Ratings[idx])*1.0 / 
 REDUCE(y = 0, k IN similarities | y+k) AS WeightedRating
```